# Pylab after upgrading

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.3

Today I upgraded to Xubuntu 13.04 which comes with Python 3.3. Before that, I was working with Pyton 3.2, which was working perfectly fine.
When running my script under Python 3.3, I get an

> ImportError: No module named 'pylab'

in import pylab.
Running in Python 3.2, which I reinstalled, throws

> ImportError: cannot import name multiarray

in import numpy.
Scipy, numpy and matplotlib are, recording to apt, on the newest version.

I don't have much knowledge about this stuff. Do you have any recommendations on how to get my script to work again, preferably on Python 3.2?
Thanks in advance,
Katrin

Edit:

We solved the problem: Apparently, there where a lot of fragments / pieces of the packages in different paths, as I installed from apt, pip as well as manually. After deleting all packages and installing them only via pip, everything works fine. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to install `python3-matplotlib`, `python3-numpy`, etc.  `python-matlab` is the python2 version.

Comment: Actually, I needed to reinstall python3-matplotlib, probably it was deleted during the upgrade. python3-numpy and python3-scipy were already installed. However, it does not work yet. With python 3.2 I get the same error, in python 3.3 I have another "ImportError: No module named 'dateutil' " in import pylab.

Comment: Which version of mpl is this?  At some point mpl stopped shipping with all it dependencies (dateutil is one of them) and it seems that the packages haven't kept up.  You also need `python3-dateutil` and should file a bug report against the ubuntu mpl package.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install all python libraries you installed for Python 3.2 [also for 3.3](http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/newbie-hint-on-installing-python-and-its-modules-and-packages/).